# nested async calls not being called after pressing the browsers refresh button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, facebook, asynchronous

```
var ctrl = {}; 

   app.controller('compFac', function($scope){   
$scope.tPHots = [];

    ctrl.tbcInject = function (result) {
        $scope.tPHots.push({URL: result});
        $scope.$apply();                            
    };

    ctrl.getFingURC= function (comURL) {
              FB.api( comURL+ '/picture', function(response) {
                  ctrl.tbcInject(response.data.url);
              });  
    };

            ctrl.getFingID= function () {
                FB.api('/5151845035415464/albums', function(response) {
                      for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                      {
                        ctrl.getFingURC(response.data[i].id);
                      }
                });
            };
ctrl.getFingID();
    )};
```

This is a snippet for a function to grab facebook photos from albums and allow them to be used by angular templating `($scope.tPHots)`. The nested calls work when I go through the webpage linearly. i.e(login > click on albums > click on photos).

However once I'm looking at the photos and the press the browsers refresh button the photos fail to be retrieved and thus cannot be displayed.

Why does this happen? Is it because of the async calls and angular? I can't figure this out.

NOTE: all other non nested async calls in the compFac controller get called.

EDIT: found new error; in regards to accessing facebook data when executing `getFingId()`. also i used facebooks sdk to implement the login function (`fb.login()`)

```
message: "An access token is required to request this resource."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the most ideal solution. but refreshing logged me out. or maybe the login process was too slow. still not 100% sure what the problem was. but i just had to check if the user was logged in, if not. log the user back in then search for the photos.

Answer (score 0):

In controller, you are assigning all function to `ctrl` object's property. When browser page refresh, when controller call all the function you have written assign to `ctrl` property but initial function which is `ctrl.getFingID` is not called. You have to called it.

Add below code at end of controller.

`ctrl.getFingID();`

and do you have defined `ctrl` variable? If not then create it below `$scope.tPHots = [];`

Comment: sorry, i forgot to copy those over. edited the answer

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle?